# Get the value between slashes

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<block4>
    <tag>
        <name>72</name>
        <value>/BNF/RED-AAF-US EQUITY GROWTH FUND //FETA/ABNAAFU000000D93--16.560-10/</value>
    </tag>
</block4>
```

i need output like **FETA** from the entire tag

i have did in xslt lik way but it ws getting fully after //

```
<xsl:for-each select="block4/tag[name = '72']">
    <xsl:value-of select="
        concat((concat(
        substringafter(value,'//'),'')),
        substringbefore(value,'/'))
        "/>
</xsl:for-each>,<xsl:text/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
substring-before(substring-after(value,'//'),'/')
```

**EDIT**

> @bluish how can i get this value ABNAAFU000000D93--16.560-10

I guess it's a new question. So here you have:

```
substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(value,'//'),'/'),'/')
```

I hope you've learnt the concepts behind these solutions. Take a look at [this good and simple reference](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/xpathFunctionIndex.html).

Comment: how can i get this value ABNAAFU000000D93--16.560-10

Comment: bro .. i hv post new question can yu please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028413/if-tag-vill-b-varies-it-should-either-a-or-d