# xslt matching tags different names

Tags: xml, xslt

```
         <xsl:for-each select ="block4">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="tag[name = '57A']">
                    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="tag[name = '57D'] ">
                    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>,<xsl:text/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

I have written my xslt like this. It's not working properly for this xml:

```
<tag>
  <name>57A</name> 
  <value>NORTESMM</value> 
</tag>
```

Sometimes the name of tags will change. It should be either **57A** or **57D**, as indicated in XSLT above. But it's not generating the proper outcome.

Comment: Define what do you mean by 'not working properly'.

Comment: my xml should varies sum times 57A tag will b there in some cases 57D tag will b there we dunno so that we need to write a condition in xslt like what ever it may be 57A or 57D we need fetch up else we need keep null

Comment: It's hard to understand what's 'not working' ... your xslt looks like a very complicated way to output the content of the `<value />` element. Please add the desired output for your sample.

Comment: <block4><tag>
  <name>57A</name> 
  <value>NORTESMM</value> 
</tag>
</block4> some times xml may comes in this manner <block4><tag>
  <name>57D</name> 
  <value>NORTESMM</value> 
</tag>
</block4> we cant expect so that i m writing an xslt for both which one is present 57A or 57D it will choose and it show ouput

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two complete, short and easy solutions that use the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern. :)

Comment: @praveen: There are too much people battling with your questions... Please, provide complete but reduce input sample, complete desired output and describe the relationship the best you can.

Answer (score 0):

Change your select to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tag/value"/>
```

Complete program:

**XML:**

```
<blocks>
  <block4>
    <tag>
      <name>57A</name>
      <value>NORTESMM</value>
    </tag>
  </block4>
  <block4>
    <tag>
      <name>57D</name>
      <value>FOO</value>
    </tag>
  </block4>
</blocks>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="blocks">
    <xsl:for-each select="block4">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="tag[name = '57A']">
          <xsl:value-of select="tag/value"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="tag[name = '57D'] ">
          <xsl:value-of select="tag/value"/>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>,<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
NORTESMM,FOO
```

Comment: @praveen It works. Maybe you should show your surrounding xsl e.g. what is your "template match"? Also provide the complete block4 xml.

Comment: <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="block4/tag[name = '57A']">
     <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise >
     <xsl:value-of select="block4/tag[name = '57D']/value"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose> even i did lik this way also it ws not wrking

Comment: <block4><tag> <name>57A</name> <value>NORTESMM</value> </tag> </block4>

Comment: @praveen I have added the complete example which works. If it still doesn't work for you, you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<xsl:for-each select ="block4">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="tag/name = '57A'">
      <xsl:value-of select="tag/value"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="tag/name = '57D'">
      <xsl:value-of select="tag/value"/>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You can test your XSLT with a simple XML, create two files test.xsl and data.xml and then open data.xml in Firefox for example:

data.xml

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?> 
 <tag>
 <name>57A</name>
 <value>NORTESMM</value>
 </tag>
```

test.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <xsl:for-each select ="block4">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="tag/name = '57A'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="tag/value"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="tag/name = '57D'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="tag/value"/>              
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: hello andre i need value ex:NORTESMM

Comment: Ok, change it to  
 <xsl:value-of select="tag/value"/>, just updated the example

Comment: Remove the <xsl:for-each select ="block4">

Comment: <block4><tag> <name>57A</name> <value>NORTESMM</value> </tag> </block4>

Comment: bro here in block 4 ..!!! so many tags vill be there similarly <block4><tag> <name>57A</name> <value>NORTESMM</value> </tag> <tag> <name>103</name> <value>123245</value> </tag> </block4>

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="block4/tag">
  <xsl:if test="name='57A' or name='57D'">
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:text>, <xsl:text/>
</xsl:template>
```

It can differ depending on how `<block4>` and `<tag>` tags are structured.

Anyway I suggest you to [learn XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=XSLT+learn) first, at least the basics, and then to use it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the shortest and the "most in the  spirit of XSLT" solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tag[name='57A']">value1 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="tag[name='57D']">value2 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
    <tag>
        <name>57A</name>
        <value>NORTESMM</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>57D</name>
        <value>NORTESMM</value>
    </tag>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
value1 value2
```

**Do note**:

1. **We use and override the identity rule**. This is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern.
2. **We don't use `<xsl:for-each>` and we don't use XSLT conditional instructions**.

**Solution 2**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:values>
  <val tagname="57A">value1 </val>
  <val tagname="57B">value2 </val>
  <val tagname="57C">value3 </val>
  <val tagname="57D">value4 </val>
  <val tagname="57E">value5 </val>
 </my:values>

 <xsl:variable name="vVals" select=
   "document('')/*/my:values/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tag">
  <xsl:value-of select="$vVals[@tagname=current()/name]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the same XML document (above), again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
value1 value4
```

**Do note**: This solution can be used when we want to treat many different possible values of `tag/name`. We use a table for the matching values and only a single overriding template.

Comment: Your answers are always great! Can you tell me what you mean with "We use and override the identity rule"? Many thanks!

Comment: @bluish: Using and overiding the identity rule (template) is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern. Read more on this here: http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html

Comment: I'd say "identity transform" rather than "identity rule."  I've never understood why the identity transform isn't the built-in template for XSLT.  Most properly-written XSLT transforms start with the identity transform (at least, ones that aren't push-style); it seems weird to have to explicitly define this all the time.

Comment: @Robert-Rossney: "Identity template" is more exact.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<xsl:for-each select ="block4">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="tag/name = '57A'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="tag/name = '57D'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>,<xsl:text/>
</xsl:for-each>
```